# Preventing user from selecting different tool when custom tool is selected?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, vb.net

I am using VB.Net to write an add-in. I'd like to keep the tool that I created selected even when the user attempts to select a different tool, and only deselect when my tool is clicked on again.

Comment: How are you implementing [ITool.Deactivate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Deactivate_Method/004300000078000000/)?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. I figured this would be the key to doing this, but I wasn't sure what to put inside the Deactivate method

Comment: When you say: "keep the tool that I created selected even when another tool is selected" do you really mean: "keep the tool that I created selected even when _the user attempts to select a different tool_"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Sorry, your interpretation was not exactly correct, what I mean is that I would like to keep my tool active, even when the user selects another tool. When the user clicks on the tool again, it should the deactivate my tool.

Comment: oops, I probably should not have edited your question then.  Perhaps it would be best if you provided more details in your question.

Comment: I'm going to repost as a better question. Here it is http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25148/7240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IApplication.currenttool` is your custom tool, return false for `ITool.Deactivate`, and set `IApplication.CurrentTool = null` in `ICommand.OnClick`.

Comment: Setting it to null tells me to convert to DBNull.Value, but this gives me the warning "Runtime errors might occur when converting 'System.DBNull' to 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem'"

Comment: @Xoph I forgot you're in VB.NET.  Did you try `Nothing` instead of `Null`?

Comment: Nothing works. I'm still hazy on where to set IApplication.CurrentTool = nothing? You say in ICommand.OnClick. Should this be a ReadOnly Property or how do I implement it?

Comment: Does this just prevent other tools from being activated?